# x:Type and arrays--how?

Tags: wpf, arrays, types, markup-extensions

Long story short, I need to do this:

```
ExpressionType="{x:Type sys:Byte[]}"
```

In other words, I need to do this:

```
foo.ExpressionType=typeof(byte[]);
```

Wat do?

---

Update:  Its a bug in the 2010 design surface.  It works fine at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no way to do it in the framework, then you can write your own markup extension:

```
public class ArrayTypeExtension
    : MarkupExtension
{
    public ArrayTypeExtension() {}

    public ArrayTypeExtension(Type type)
    {
        this.Type = type;
    }

    public Type Type { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Type == null ? null : Type.MakeArrayType();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ExpressionType="{local:ArrayType sys:Byte}"
```

Actually, just doing {x:Type sys:Byte[]} seems to work.

Comment: @Will: Actually, just doing `{x:Type sys:Byte[]}` seems to work for me.  What's happening when you try it?

Comment: You must not be generating the error correctly (?!?!).  You should get the error "Type sys:Byte[] not found."  It will build, but fails when run.  Try adding `DataContext="{x:Type sys:Byte[]}"` to a new WPF forms project and run it.

Comment: VS2008; New Project / WPF Application; add `<ContentControl xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Content="{x:Type sys:Byte[]}"/>` to the Grid and run; I get a window that displays 'System.Byte[]'.

Comment: That explains it.  Its a bug in 2010.  I can run it, but I get that exception when I hit it in the designer.  I'll pass it along to MS.  Accepting.

Comment: Bloody hell, I just wound up back here again.  Would upvote again if I could.