# DataTemplate for an array or IEnumerable

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, datatemplate

I would like to create an implicit DataTemplate that works on an array or IEnumerable of my class. This way I have a template that describes how to render a bunch of items instead of just one. I want to do this so I can, among other things, show the results in a tooltip. eg

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CustomerName}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Invoices}">
```

The tooltip should see that Invoices is a bunch of items and use the appropriate data template. The template would look something like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Customer[]}">
    <ListBox "ItemsSource={Binding}">
     etc
```

That didn't work so I tried the example from this post [x:Type and arrays--how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268495/xtype-and-arrays-how) which involves creating a custom markup extension. This works if you specify the key but not for an implicit template

So then I tried making my own custom markup extension inheriting from TypeExtension like below but I get an error that says "A key for a dictionary cannot be of type 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel'. Only String, TypeExtension, and StaticExtension are supported." This is a really weird error as it is taking the content of the datatemplate as the key?? If I specify a key then it works fine but that largely defeats the purpose.

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(Type)), TypeForwardedFrom("PresentationFramework, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")]
public class ArrayTypeExtension
    : TypeExtension
{
    public ArrayTypeExtension() : base() { }

    public ArrayTypeExtension(Type type) : base(type)
    {
    }

    public ArrayTypeExtension(string value) : base(value)
    {
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        Type val = base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider) as Type;
        return val == null ? null : val.MakeArrayType();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just create the data template for the single object, and then bind the list to a `ListBox`?

Comment: That's true but in some cases it is preferable. In my case I am presenting the data in a DataGrid so you can't specify a template for each item, you need a template for each column. In other cases it would just be handy to be able to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the question you linked to `{x:Type ns:TypeName[]}` *works*. It may screw over the designer but at runtime it should be fine.

To avoid designer errors the template can be moved to App.xaml or a resource dictionary (or of course just don't use the designer at all).

(The error mentioning the control inside the template sounds like a bug in the code generator or compiler, sadly i doubt that there is much you can do about that one.)

Comment: Hi HB, thanks for the reply. I didn't realise this was just a designer error. Even though it does work I still don't think it is a good solution to have errors appearing in the build like that. Basically this error is what I am trying to eliminate. I tried my own markup extension but that was no good. BTW, I did have the xmlns in my code, I just didn't put it in the question as I typed it by hand. Consider it Pseudo Code. :-)

Comment: @MikeKulls: I will have to disagree on the error issue, they are completely artificial, it's not a problem in the build it's just the visual studio designer being a piece of junk. I for one would never even notice any such "errors" because i don't use the designer and hence they *do not even occur* in the first place. The error mentioning the control inside the template sounds like a bug in the code generator or compiler, sadly i doubt that there is much you can do about that one.

Comment: I'm afraid we will have to disagree on that one. :-) I realise the designer is a piece of junk and I don't use it that much myself but there are uses for it. However I did find a workaround that so far appears to give the best of both worlds and is actually what I wanted anyway. You just move the DataTemplate into App.xaml or a resource dictionary. There is no designer so no errors at all. Can you add this as an edit to your answer for the future generations of programmers to see?

Comment: @MikeKulls: I made an edit (you could have suggested one, and you can still do of course if you think it can be improved)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm still relatively new here :-) I did notice one interesting issue in that if you click the little arrow at the bottom of the XAML view then the entire IDE crashes out. I'm not sure what that array is called but it has "Resource Dictionary Resource Dictionary" written next to it on mine. I very rarely use that feature anyway so no loss. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are OK with creating your own type, I just tried and following and it is working. Create a specific type for your collection:

```
public class InvoiceCollection : List<Invoice> { }

public class Customer {
    public string name { get; set; }
    InvoiceCollection invoices { get; set; }
}
```

and then the XAML with data template:

```
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type InvoiceCollection}>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>

<TextBox Text="{Binding name}" Tooltip="{Binding invoices}" />
```

Comment: I would consider this to be a good options also. It has the advantage that it appears to be a more stable option in VS2010 with the slight disadvantage of a little more typing.